# Como separar um número em dois

Tags: java

Como eu poderia separar um número com decimais em dois outros números? A ideia é a seguinte: ao dar entrada em um número no terminal, por exemplo 125,69, ao passar o número para o código puxar as duas primeiras casas (decimais 69) para uma variável, e o número real (125) para outra variável.

```
package eng_software;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class alg {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double valorEntrada = sc.nextDouble();
  }
}
```

Necessito saber o tipo de comando para fracionar o número e enviá-lo para outras variáveis.

Answer (score 8):

```
double real = Math.floor(valorEntrada);
double frac = valorEntrada % 1;
```

Comment: Muito boa solução, limpa e de simples compreensão!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Pois é, a pergunta não é clara. Se forem sempre duas casas decimais, pode-se fazer `int x = (int) (valorEntrada * 100); int real = x / 100; int frac = x % 100;`. Mas a pergunta não deixa muito claro o propósito.

Answer (score 1):

Esse caso em específico pode ser trabalhado com strings. Não gosto tanto assim da alternativa de ponto flutuante para fazer uma resposta devido ao [problema com pontos flutuantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219465/64969).

Então, como resolver o problema? Bem, lendo uma string. E trabalhando com string. E se mantendo apenas em string.

Considerando que o retorno seja um objeto de classe `PartesNumero` com os campos `String parteInteira` e `String parteDecimal`, poderíamos fazer o seguinte construtor:

```
public PartesNumero(String numeroCompleto) {
  String partes[] = numeroCompleto.split("[^0-9]");

  if ("".equals(partes[0]) {
    this.parteInteira = 0; // fallback para entradas como ".75"
  } else {
    this.parteInteira = partes[0];
  }
  if (partes.length > 1) {
    this.parteDecimal = partes[1];
  } else {
    this.parteDecimal = "";
  }
}
```

E para ler [uma string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) da entrada (não fazendo validação quanto ao seu tipo, entretanto):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada = sc.next();
```

O programa completo então seria:

```
public class Main {
  public class PartesNumero {
    public final String parteInteira;
    public final String parteDecimal;

    public PartesNumero(String numeroCompleto) {
      String partes[] = numeroCompleto.split("[^0-9]");

      if ("".equals(partes[0]) {
        this.parteInteira = 0; // fallback para entradas como ".75"
      } else {
        this.parteInteira = partes[0];
      }
      if (partes.length > 1) {
        this.parteDecimal = partes[1];
      } else {
        this.parteDecimal = "";
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entrada = sc.next();
    PartesNumero partes = new PartesNumero(entrada);
    System.out.println(partes.parteInteira);
    System.out.println(partes.parteDecimal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double x = 125.69;
    double decimal = x % 1;
    double inteiro = x - decimal;
    System.out.println("Decimal: "+decimal);
    System.out.println("Inteiro: "+inteiro);
```